# drive from China to UK in Chinese registered car

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china, driving, russia, eu

My husband wants to drive his Chinese registered car from China to UK across Kazakhstan, south west Russia and across Europe to UK to raise money for charity.  Do you know of a car insurance company that will insure him?  UK based companies won't because the car is registered in China and has Chinese plates. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You will need what is often called a **Green Card** Insurance coverage, which is based on the [International Motor Insurance Card System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Motor_Insurance_Card_System)

- for at least **Russia** and the **European Union**

for a car registered in China.

This is the **term** you need to ask for and

- make sure the countries you want to drive through are listed  (see image below)

Do you intend to drive it back to China?

If not, you may face high import fees, in this case probably in the  United Kingdom.

---

[Car insurance validity in the EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/insurance/validity/index_en.htm)

> When you register a car in any EU country(In this case, the 28 EU member states + Iceland, Liechtenstein and Norway), you must insure it for third party liability. This compulsory insurance is valid in all other EU countries. It covers you if you have an accident causing damage to property or injury to anyone other than the driver. It doesn't cover other costs (e.g. the cost of repairs to your own vehicle).

[image]

Comment: downvoters, care to comment?

Comment: Why downvote this? It’s exactly the correct answer